# Erro ao criar uma simples tabela no Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

Estou com problemas para criar a tabela a seguir:

```
CREATE TABLE T_AM_OME_ADVOGADO
(
cd_pessoa   NUMBER (8) NOT NULL ,
nr_oab      NUMBER (8) NOT NULL ,
nr_cpf      NUMBER (11) NOT NULL ,
nr_rg       CHAR (10) NOT NULL ,
ds_email    VARCHAR2 (128) NOT NULL ,
ds_password VARCHAR2 (40)
) ;
ALTER TABLE T_AM_OME_ADVOGADO ADD CONSTRAINT PK_AM_ADVOGADO PRIMARY KEY (     cd_pessoa ) ;
ALTER TABLE T_AM_OME_ADVOGADO ADD CONSTRAINT UN_AM_ADVOGADO_CPF UNIQUE ( nr_cpf ) ;
ALTER TABLE T_AM_OME_ADVOGADO ADD CONSTRAINT UN_AM_ADVOGADO_RG UNIQUE ( nr_rg ) ;
ALTER TABLE T_AM_OME_ADVOGADO ADD CONSTRAINT UN_AM_ADVOGADO_OAB UNIQUE ( nr_oab ) ;
```

Relatório de erros

```
Erro a partir da linha : 10 no comando -
ALTER TABLE T_AM_OME_ADVOGADO ADD CONSTRAINT PK_AM_ADVOGADO PRIMARY KEY (         cd_pessoa ) 
Relatório de erros -
Erro de SQL: ORA-02264: nome já usado por uma restrição existente
02264. 00000 -  "name already used by an existing constraint"
*Cause:    The specified constraint name has to be unique.
*Action:   Specify a unique constraint name for the constraint.


Erro a partir da linha : 11 no comando -
ALTER TABLE T_AM_OME_ADVOGADO ADD CONSTRAINT UN_AM_ADVOGADO_CPF UNIQUE (     nr_cpf ) 
Relatório de erros -
Erro de SQL: ORA-02264: nome já usado por uma restrição existente
02264. 00000 -  "name already used by an existing constraint"
*Cause:    The specified constraint name has to be unique.
*Action:   Specify a unique constraint name for the constraint.


Erro a partir da linha : 12 no comando -
ALTER TABLE T_AM_OME_ADVOGADO ADD CONSTRAINT UN_AM_ADVOGADO_RG UNIQUE (     nr_rg ) 
Relatório de erros -
Erro de SQL: ORA-02264: nome já usado por uma restrição existente
02264. 00000 -  "name already used by an existing constraint"
*Cause:    The specified constraint name has to be unique.
*Action:   Specify a unique constraint name for the constraint.


Erro a partir da linha : 13 no comando -
ALTER TABLE T_AM_OME_ADVOGADO ADD CONSTRAINT UN_AM_ADVOGADO_OAB UNIQUE (     nr_oab ) 
Relatório de erros -
Erro de SQL: ORA-02264: nome já usado por uma restrição existente
02264. 00000 -  "name already used by an existing constraint"
*Cause:    The specified constraint name has to be unique.
*Action:   Specify a unique constraint name for the constraint.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu banco de dados já tem as seguintes constraints:

- PK_AM_ADVOGADO
- UN_AM_ADVOGADO_CPF
- UN_AM_ADVOGADO_RG
- UN_AM_ADVOGADO_OAB

Use outro nome para as constraits que está criando agora
(ou remova as constraits antigas se for o caso)

Comment: `Erro a partir da linha : 5 no comando -
ALTER TABLE T_AM_OME_ADVOGADO DROP CONSTRAINT PK_AM_ADVOGADO
Relatório de erros -
Erro de SQL: ORA-02443: Não é possível eliminar restrição - restrição não existe
02443. 00000 -  "Cannot drop constraint  - nonexistent constraint"
*Cause:    alter table drop constraint <constraint_name>
*Action:   make sure you supply correct constraint name.`

Comment: Deve haver outra tabela com uma contraint com esse mesmo nome. Você pode usar isso pra consultar todas as contraints exitstentes: `SELECT * FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS`